# Odoo 10 : Auto install custom modules on odoo start

Tags: module, installation, customization, manifest, odoo

Is there any way to auto install or upgrade my custom modules when i start my odoo?

I tried

```
'installable': True,
    'auto_install': True,
    'active': True,
```

in my manifest file. but still i have to install my module manually.

Comment: 'auto_install': True - works only only when you create a new database

Answer (score 1):

You can Odoo tell on start (for example in default Debian as service you will find everything in `/etc/init.d/odoo`) by using following parameters:

-d

specify a database

-i

comma-separated list of modules to install

-u

comma-separated list of modules to update

For example (Odoo 12):
`odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf -d my_database -i website -u sale`

will start Odoo with the given configfile and install app "Website" and update App "Sale" on database my_database.

The manifest key `auto_install` is only for auto installation, when all module dependencies are satisfied. One simple example: After installing sale and stock you will find sale_stock also installed, because it has auto_install set and depends on sale and stock.